# How to mock using Mockito and assert a thrown exception and message using Junit5?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am using Mockito along with Junit5 as well as SpringBootTest. I need to assert a thrown exception as well as its message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;


@SpringBootTest
class Sample{

   @Autowired
   TestService service;

   @Test
   void sampleTest(){
      Executable exec = ()-> service.execute();
      Throwable thrown = assertThrows(MyException.class, exec, "Type your message");        
      assertEquals("Dancing stars", thrown.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please refer doc [here](https://www.codingrevolution.com/junit-5-expected-exception/#asserting-exception-message).